# how to trigger a php program to run from a drupal page

Tags: drupal

Drupal 6.25 - our Drupal site was developed years ago prior to much of Drupal's current capabilities.  So a lot of its function was custom coded in php and embedded within the body of the page.   Unfortunately Drupal 6.x doesn't like that and the wysiwyg edit literally destroys the php code.
What I've done is to extract the complete code from the database and saved it as a file in the Drupal sites directory tree.  But now I'm trying to figure out how to invoke that file when the given page is accessed.

I've tried the following:

php include("sites/default/files/program_name.php");

But this doesn't work either.

Surely someone out there must be doing this so as I continue to search I am hoping that someone will be kind enough to share their working ideas with us readers?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried including it as you would include a template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [creating a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/231276), implementing [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu/6) to define a path for your custom script and calling your custom php script from the menu callback.

Your module code could look something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['myscript'] = array(
    'title' => 'My PHP script',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'file' => 'my_php_script.php', // This tells Drupal to include your custom php file.
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_myscript_page',
  );
}

function mymodule_myscript_page() {
  $output = run_my_awesome_php_script();
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks marcvangend for your reply.  My further research let me to a similar approach (which seems convoluted for what needs to be done) and I will explore more.  BTW, I see that my Q was closed as off topic!  Seeing how I work ONLY with Drupal 99.999% of the time and this is a question to accomplish something already being done in Drupal by others, I am offended that its deemed off topic.

Comment: Well to be honest, I agree that it's off topic. Stackoverflow is about programming, while your Q is rather about implementing/configuring something that has already been programmed. While I didn't vote for your question to be closed, I *did* flag it for moderation, saying that it should be moved to http://drupal.stackexchange.com.